# Integrating edge.js with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, edge.js

How can I add syntax highlighting to [edge.js](https://edge.adonisjs.com/) template files in IntelliJ IDEA / Webstorm?

There is no obvious plugin available. Perhaps there is something for a similar templating engine that would work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, i got my answer.

Edge.js is similar to Blade template engine (which is used in Laravel) and after installing Blade plugin in IntelliJ IDEA you should add .edge extension in blade file types:

`Settings => Editor => File Types => find Blade => add *.edge pattern using + icon`